# How does a MetaMask seed phrase reproduce all subsequent accounts?

Tags: metamask, wallets

I have read that a seed phrase can deterministically recreate a master private key, which in turn can deterministically recreate child keys, in order to be used to subsequent accounts for a variety of different blockchain accounts. Ok, let's say I initially create a new MetaMask seed phrase / master key with my initial bitcoin account, and then I add an account from the Ethereum blockchain, and then one from the Binance Smart Chain. If I uninstall MetaMask and delete all cache files, and then try to recover my MetaMask wallet with my seed phrase, **how will MetaMask know how many accounts it will have to create, which blockchains, in what order, etc?** Does MetaMask store extra info for my account, like which blockchain accounts my MetaMask account used to have?

Comment: thank you for guiding me

Comment: no worries! The topic you mentioned is derived from similar bitcoin software design, however is still too disconnected from it to be discussed here practically.